# How can I force a TRichedit control to fire up the onRequestResize in Delphi 11.3?

Tags: delphi, trichedit

Somewhere in my app I have the statement `RE.Lines.LoadFromStream(st)` where `RE` is a `TRichEdit` control.

I have also set the event `onResizeRequest` that fires up on execution of the above statement but not every time although the event remains assigned.

The code is big and I can't cut a part of it to show it.

Can I add some command, for example `RE.Perform(.....)` that will force the control to execute the event (or even better not to use an event but a `function` that I will call whenever I want)?

Comment: Could you describe one specific case where the OnResizeRequest is not called?

Comment: I noticed that it happens after execution of the statement `RE.Height := 0`. If I comment out this statement the event fires up again. `RE.Height := 0` is essential, I can't remove it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to call common procedure from `OnResizeRequest` handler and after `RE.Lines.LoadFromStream` rather than emulating `WM_NOTIFY` / `CN_NOTIFY`?

Comment: @PeterWolf, I am not sure understood you. `OnRequestResize` doesn't be called after `RE.Height := 0` execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an implementation detail of rich edit control that the common controls library prevents generating [`EN_REQUESTRESIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-requestresize) notification when the width or height of the control is zero.

To force `EN_REQUESTRESIZE` notification, send [`EM_REQUESTRESIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-requestresize) message to rich edit control's window. This will generate the notification regardless of the control's size.

```
SendMessage(RE.Handle, EM_REQUESTRESIZE, 0, 0);
```

`CRichEditCtrl` from MFC has a dedicated method [`RequestResize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/lv-LV/cpp/mfc/reference/cricheditctrl-class?view=msvc-150#requestresize) for that. To mimic that you can implement a class helper:

```
uses
  Vcl.ComCtrls, Winapi.RichEdit;

type
  TCustomRichEditHelper = class helper for TCustomRichEdit
  public
    procedure RequestResize;
  end;

procedure TCustomRichEditHelper.RequestResize;
begin
  if HandleAllocated then
    SendMessage(Handle, EM_REQUESTRESIZE, 0, 0);
end;
```

You can then call:

```
RE.RequestResize;
```